# Remove hover effect after the element has moved away from mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make some animation effects where a Menu button when clicked splits into three sub-menus. I am facing 2 problems in this:

1. Sub-menu icons overlap the menu icon and then start moving. This is
       because I have kept the JS code in such manner because lately, I
       want to show the movement of the sub-menu icons. I know the reason
       but unable to fix it.
2. When clicked on Menu icon, the hover effect of third sub-menu remains and goes only after the mouse is
   slightly moved. This happens because its initial position is where
   the mouse is clicked. I can't figure out, how to prevent this thing
   from happening.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li class="text-center admin-menu-item">
     <a id="applicationMenuBtn" class="User admin-menu-btn animates">
      <i class="app-master-data-icon admin-icon"></i><br />
          Application Master Data
     </a>
     <div class="dashboard-submenu-wrapper animates" id="applicationMenu">
     <a href="#/manageApplicationUser" class="dashboard-submenu-item dashboard-submenu-item-one animates">
      <i class="users-icon admin-sub-icon"></i><br />
      Users
     </a>
     <a href="#/manageProjects" class="dashboard-submenu-item dashboard-submenu-item-two animates">
      <i class="users-icon admin-sub-icon"></i><br />
      Create Project
     </a>
     <a href="#/manageUserMapping" class="dashboard-submenu-item dashboard-submenu-item-three animates">
      <i class="users-icon admin-sub-icon"></i><br />
       User Mapping
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
</ul>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#applicationMenuBtn").on('click', function(){
    var parentLi = $(this).parents('li');
    var adminMenu = parentLi.find('>div');
    var adminMenuBtn = parentLi.find('>a');
    adminMenuBtn.addClass('admin-menu-btn-animate').removeClass('admin-menu-reset');
    adminMenu.show().addClass('submenu-visible');
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    adminMenu.find('.dashboard-submenu-item-one').css('transform', 'translate(135%, -100%)');
    adminMenu.find('.dashboard-submenu-item-two').css('transform', 'translate(100%, 0)');
    adminMenu.find('.dashboard-submenu-item-three').css('transform', 'translate(54%, 100%)');
});

$(".overlay").on('click', function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    $('.submenu-visible').fadeOut(200).removeClass('submenu-visible');
    $('.admin-menu-btn').removeClass('admin-menu-btn-animate').addClass('admin-menu-reset');
    $('.dashboard-submenu-item-one, .dashboard-submenu-item-two, .dashboard-submenu-item-three').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
});
    });
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.admin-menu-item {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 40px 14px;
    position: relative;
}

.admin-menu-item a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #E50654;
}
.admin-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 13px 15px;
}

.admin-sub-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 0;
}

.app-master-data-icon,
.users-icon {
    background-image: url("http://www.icosy.com/images/icons/career_icon.png");
}
.admin-menu-item .dashboard-submenu-item i {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.dashboard-submenu-wrapper {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

.dashboard-submenu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 17%;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #e50654;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}

.dashboard-submenu-item:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.admin-menu-btn-animate {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

.admin-menu-reset {
    transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.animates {
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufcabxeb/1/)

Comment: z-index should fix both the issue. the main icon should have more z-index than the animated icons that breakthrough

Comment: I've tried z-index. Apparently, it did not fix the issue. :(

Comment: Very good question. have you found the answer ?

Comment: applicationMenuBtn i gave z-index:1000;position:relative seems to be working

Comment: @DeepakDavid Can't give `position: relative;` to applicationMenuBtn. It just breaks the UI. Please give it a try on Fiddle.

Comment: @Zl3n No resolution found yet. :(

Comment: HI @VibhorDube, tweaking z-index seems to be the only workaround here. Check this ***[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufcabxeb/5/)***. Notice the `hoverTweak` class in CSS and last lines of each click handler.

Comment: @ShaunakD, You nailed it. Though the first question is still open, please post your solution as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer,

The workaround here can be tweaking the z-index on every transition event.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufcabxeb/5/)**

Notice the below CSS changes

```
.hoverTweak{    //new class
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.dashboard-submenu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 17%;
    z-index: 0;            //change
    color: #e50654;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the approach you are following. I see very complicated HTML and CSS and then JS as well. Simplifying it resolves the issue.

I am not good in CSS animations, so I didn't achive the same effect as you got but something similar I have done without the issue. Try this, may be you get the fix.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/gvqc3yn8/

```js
$(function(){
    var $menuContainer = $("#container"),
        $defaultMenu = $menuContainer.find(".default"),
        $allMenuItems = $menuContainer.find(".nav");
    
    //
    function toggleMenu(){
        $allMenuItems.toggleClass("active");
    }
    
    //
    $defaultMenu.on("click", toggleMenu);
});
```

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.nav {
    background:#FFF url("http://www.icosy.com/images/icons/career_icon.png") top center no-repeat;
    color: #E50654;
    cursor: pointer;
    font:16px normal "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 90px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.n1:hover, .n2:hover, .n3:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.nav.active{
    background-color: transparent;
    
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-20%) translateY(-5%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

.n1.active{
    top: 0;
    left: 80px
}

.n2.active{    
    left: 140px
}

.n3.active{
    top: 220px;
    left: 80px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="nav n1">Users</div>
    <div class="nav n2">Create Project</div>
    <div class="nav n3">User Mapping</div>
    <div class="nav default">Application Master Data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AshishKumar. Your solution works well but does not answer my questions. You changed the behavior of the sub-menu icons. I want them to appear as if they are popping out from the Menu icon.

Comment: May some change in the CSS, will get you the same effect. Try this once. As I mentioned above, I am not very good in CSS animations, otherwise I definately would have helped you...

Comment: That is what I am struggling with. I know CSS and have implemented in a manner that all 3 sub-icons have there initial position as that of the main icon. Then apply transition to that so they'll appear as they are coming from the main icon.